# String Replace not working with a MySQLi Fetch Row Result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli, str-replace

The PHP function `str_replace()` is failing to work with the output from a `mysqli_fetch_row()` result. It just outputs the original string without any alterations.

Assuming `$row[1] = Hello \\r\\n This needs it's own line BOO.`

**Code:**

```
$result = get_posts($database, $_GET['id'], $page);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
     echo str_replace('\\r\\n', '<br>', $row[1]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello \\r\\n This needs it's own line BOO.
```

But below when I attach additional string it properly replaces but the original varible doesn't.

**Code:**

```
$result = get_posts($database, $_GET['id'], $page);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
     echo str_replace('\\r\\n', '<br>', $row[1].'\\r\\n For some reason I replace.');
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello \\r\\n This needs it's own line BOO. <br> For some reason I replace.
```

I also tried using `nl2br()` but the results stay the same, however, pasting the sentence as it's own string in quotes into a `str_replace()` works.

I assume this has to do with the original varible and I need some sort of fix for it. I am welcome to using JQuery and Javascript as a part of my solution. If more code is needed please request in a comment.

Comment: what if you tried `$str = mb_convert_encoding($row[1], "UTF-8");` then you did the replace process

Comment: @MaveRick I just tried that and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: what if you tried `echo str_replace('\\n', '<br>', $row[1]);`
 this way your will check if there is a utf control char between these two chars `\\n` and `\\r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The PHP function str_replace() is failing to work with the output from a mysqli_fetch_row() result.

Nah – *you* are failing to feed it the *correct* parameter :-)

> Assuming `$row[1] = Hello \\r\\n This needs it's own line BOO.`

If you actually have double backslashes in your data there, then you need to have the same amount of backslashes in your search expression as well.

Now do you? Let’s have a look:

```
str_replace('\\r\\n', '<br>', $row[1]);
```

Let’s take that first argument, and output it:

```
echo '\\r\\n';
```

Output: `\r\n` – oops, just single backslashes …?

The backslash is the *escape character*, and to *take* that special meaning from it – even in single-quoted strings – another backslash is put in front of it. So what you have here, is the first backslash escaping the second one, therefor leaving you with *one single* backslash in your actual parsed text literal.

So you have to *double* those backslashes for them to actually mean “two literal backslashes”:

```
echo '\\\\r\\\\n';
```

Ah, that outputs `\\r\\n` … ain’t that nice.

So, what you actually want to use for your replacing, is

```
str_replace('\\\\r\\\\n', '<br>', $row[1]);
```

(Using only *three* backslashes would work as well here, since the first one would mask the second then, and the third would be “stand-alone” and taken literally, because after it there is no character that has special meaning in a single-quoted string. But to avoid confusion – and just out of principle – it’s better to double them both.)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this has to do with the encoding of the data you are pulling from the database. Try encoding it to UTF-8 before replacing.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
    echo str_replace('\\r\\n', '<br>', utf8_encode($row[1]));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am not able to use this solution, as it does not work as a solution.